# @font-face in safari 5.5 with font-weight: normal; and font-style: normal; doesn't work

Tags: html, css, fonts, safari

I've a problem with the @font-face declaration. In Firefox and Chrome works but in Safari 5.5 doesn't work, i see the Times New Roman font when I put in the declaration the MinionPro-Regular font. I searched in other questions about this problem and I put the font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; but the problem persists. I generated the @font-face code with web font generator of Font Squirrel.

My @font-face declaration is this

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MinionPro-Regular';
src: url('/fonts/MinionPro-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), 
     url('/fonts/MinionPro-Regular.otf')  format('opentype'),
     url('/fonts/MinionPro-Regular.woff') format('woff'), 
     url('/fonts/MinionPro-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'),
     url('/fonts/MinionPro-Regular.svg#MinionPro-Regular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

The css is this

```
#block-system-main-menu{
font-family: 'MinionPro-Regular';
font-size: 22px;
letter-spacing: 3px;
line-height:1.2;
}
```

What happens?

Thanks!

Comment: “Doesn’t work” is not a problem description. Explain what you expected and what happened instead. Moreover, always when having a problem with downloadable font, describe where you got the font from and how you generated the different font files, so that others can reconstruct the situation.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Sorry, i edited the question.